# How can the following mathematical statement proven?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, set-partition

So, I have the statement that if $g: [k]\to[k]$ is a bijection, then $f: [n] \to[k]$ and $g\circ f: [n] \to[k]$ give the same partition of $[n].$

My thought process was that $g\circ f$ would be actually $[n] \to[k]\to[k]$ and because $[k] \to[k]$ in
$[n] \to[k] \to[k]$ is a bijection, which is function $g,$ is a bijection, the partitioning of $[n]$ actually should be the same. I tried to use Bell Numbers to show that they have the same partition but it didn't work for me.  I'm right now struggling how to prove this statement by inclusion-exclusion, induction or combinatorial proof, could anyone help me to how to prove this statement in either ways?

Comment: Inclusion-exclusion is a counting tool, and can’t really be used in a question like this one. Here, you have to define what it means for a map $[n]\to [k]$ to represent a partition, and what a partition is.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews So, a partition for a set of [n], let's say set A, represents a collection of non-empty subsets, ⊆A , 1≤≤ (the parts of the partition), and for a map []→[] to represent a partition, should I think like it means that it is the number of partitions of  into exactly  parts?

Comment: Well, a map $g;[n]\to [k]$ represents a partition into $k$ parts only if $g$ is surjective. In general, it represents a partition into $k$ or fewer parts. If you don’t have a clear idea of what the relationship is between functions and partitions, maybe you started with the wrong question.

Answer (score 1):

Partition as in quotient? Quotient by kernel? Sure, we have for all $a,b\in \{1,\ldots, n\}$
$$ f(a) = f(b) \Leftrightarrow gf(a) = gf(b)\qquad (g\text{ is injective}) $$
In other words $\ker f = \ker gf$.

---

The kernel of a map $h:[n]\to [k]$ is an equivalence relation (reflexive, transitive and symmetric) on $[n]$ defined by
$$ (a,b)\in \ker h \subseteq [n]\times [n] \Leftrightarrow h(a) = h(b) $$
A set can be quotiented by an equivalence relation. The quotient is a set that consists of equivalence classes:
$$ [n] / \ker h = \left\{ \overline{a} \mid a\in [n] \right \} $$
where $\overline{a} = \{x\in [n] \mid h(a) = h(x)\}$. This division into equivalence classes is also called a partition on $[n]$.

Comment: Could you explain a little bit more by what do you mean by quotient and kernel? I'm not familiar with the terms Kernel and Quotient, but I believe that simpler form of your answer is the actual answer to this question. Thank you a lot!

Comment: @Xemorphy These are standard concepts. If you say a function induces a partition, one immediately thinks of quotient by the kernel.

Comment: In the question it says that there would be the same partition of [], so if we think how the map []→[] to represent a partition, we would think that function induces a  partition, is this inducing meaning that the number of partitions of  into exactly  parts?

Comment: @Xemorphy That depends on $f$. If $f$ is a constant function, then there will only be one "block" in the partition - all of $[n]$. More generally, the number of parts in the partition is determined by how many different values $f$ takes. If $f$ is surjective, then yes, there are exactly $k$ parts.

Comment: thank your for your answer. So, for the proof, do you think that this question also can be written for combinatorial proof or do you think that the quotient by the kernel is the only answer, additionally if we think that it's not constant but injective, the previous statement I said, would still be incorrect right?

Comment: @Xemorphy $f:[n]\to [k]$ can be injective only if $n\leqslant k$ and if it is injective, it has $n$ different values. As for the proof - it requires nothing more than introductory concepts from set theory.

Comment: What does this question tell us about the relationship between S(n, k) and the number of surjections from [n] to [k]? I thought that if there's number of surjections,  :[]→[]  can be surjective only if >= and if it is surjective, then there would be the number of partitions of n into exactly k parts, which would give us S(n,k)k!, because these each element can be associated with any of the k parts, but I would love to also hear your ideas about that. Again, thank you for all your help, when I get the enough reputation, I will upvote you :)